# Minimagick not reducing png filesize instead its increasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-6, minimagick

I want to compress my images only when the size is greater than 200kb before uploading them to s3 bucket,In my case images are not connected with any model, I am directly uploading it to s3 using storage as aws

My Uploader is

```
class CoverImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  #include CarrierWave::RMagick
  
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   process :compress_image, if: :size_is_large?

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :aws
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def initialize(location_id)
    @location_id = location_id
  end


  def store!(*args)
    super
    @file
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/cover-images/#{@location_id}"
  end

  def compress_image
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.quality("60")
      img
    end
  end

  def size_is_large? picture
    image = MiniMagick::Image.new(picture.path)
    (image[:size]/1000) > 200
  end
end
```

I am using following code to upload the image

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(https://abc.s3.amazon.com/uploads/image.png)
              image_type = image.type.downcase
              image_name = "#{location}.#{image_type}"
              image_path = Rails.root.join("tmp", image_name)
              file = File.open(image_path, 'wb') do |output|
                 output.write RestClient.get(cover_image["url"])
                 output.path
               end
               uploader = CoverImageUploader.new("test123")
               s3_path = File.open(file) do |file|
                          uploaded_image = uploader.store!(file)
                          uploaded_image.url
                        end
```

For jpg and jpeg the above code is working fine but in case of png image, instead of decreasing the size its increasing the image size
My file size was 602 kb in png but it got increased to 1.3 mb  after uploading it to s3
I want it to be compressed so the image can load faster on our webpages.
Can anyone please suggest what should I do for png image to be compressed ?

Comment: If you're not reliant on potential transparency data in the png just convert it to jpeg and your'e done.

Comment: @bkunzi01 , Yes I am reliant on transparency data as well